# TensorFlow: Getting a Sub-Tensor from a Tensor Using Indexing

Tags: tensorflow

`A` is a `tensorflow.tensor` with shape `(2261,)`

I want to get a new tensor from the following indixes of `A`: `[10,20,30]`

I tried all the followings, but none work:

```
A[[10,20,30]]
# *** ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [2261], [3], [3], [3].

A[10,20,30]
# same error as above 

A[numpy.array([10,20,30])]
# *** ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [2261], [1,3], [1,3], [1].

A[10]
# <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=float32> - not an error but a shapeless tensor

A[tensorflow.constant(10)]
# same problem as above
```

Why are these not working, and what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(A, B)
```

where B is a tensor with the values [10,20,30]

For reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/embeddings

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the gather function.

```
B = tf.constant([10, 20, 30])
tf.gather(A, B)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather

Answer (score 0):

I don't think fancy indexing like that is supported yet in TensorFlow. Keep an eye on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206 for updates (maybe there is somewhere else too).

If you'd like to see what *is* available, it looks like they have some documentation about [`__tensor.__getitem__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Tensor.__getitem__).