# How to create a sub-tensor from a given tensor by selecting windows around some values of this tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, slice, embedding

My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294064/tensorflow-getting-a-sub-tensor-from-a-tensor-using-indexing). The difference is that I would like to have a new tensor `B` that's a concatenation of some selected windows from the initial tensor `A`. **The objective is to do it with a priori unknown tensors, ie: Input layers.** Here is an example using defined constants just to explain what I would like to do:

Given 2 input tensors of 3-dim embeddings:

```
A = K.constant([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [2, 2, 2], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10]])
t = K.constant([[2, 2, 2], [6, 6, 6], [10, 10, 10]])
```

I would like to create a tensor `B` that is a concatenation of the following sub-tensors (or windows) selected from `A` and that correspond to occurence neighbourhood of each element in `t`:

```
# windows of 3 elements, each window is a neighbourhood of a corresponding element in t
window_t_1 = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]  # 1st neighbourhood of [2, 2, 2] 
window_t_2 = [[7, 7, 7], [2, 2, 2], [8, 8, 8]]  # 2nd neighbourhood of [2, 2, 2] (because it has 2 occurences in A)
window_t_3 = [[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7]]  # unique neighbourhood of [6, 6, 6]
window_t_4 = [[8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10]]  # unique neighbourhood of [10, 10, 10]
# B must contain these selected widows:
B = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [7, 7, 7], [2, 2, 2], [8, 8, 8], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10]]
```

The objective is to apply this process to reformulate the `Input` tensors of my model, instead of pre-defined constants. So, how can I do this given the two inputs of my model:

```
in_A = Input(shape=(10,), dtype="int32")
in_t = Input(shape=(3,), dtype="int32")
embed_A = Embedding(...)(in_A)
embed_t = Embedding(...)(in_t)
B = ...  # some function or layer to create the tensor B as described in the example above using embed_A and embed_t
# B will be used then on the next layer like this:
# next_layer = some_other_layer(...)(embed_t, B)
```

Or selecting the sub-tensor elements then apply the embedding layer:

```
in_A = Input(shape=(10,), dtype="int32")
in_t = Input(shape=(3,), dtype="int32")
B = ...  # some function to select the desired element windows as described above
embed_B = Embedding(...)(B)
embed_t = Embedding(...)(in_t)
# then add the next layer like this:
# next_layer = some_other_layer(...)(embed_t, embed_B)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are w1,..., w4 from?

Comment: @Jie.Zhou I've just added an explanation of the different elements w1...w4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import autograph
# you can uncomment next line to enable eager execution to see what happens at each step, you'd better use the up-to-date tf-nightly to run this code
# tf.enable_eager_execution()
A = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],
                 [2, 2, 2],
                 [3, 3, 3],
                 [4, 4, 4],
                 [5, 5, 5],
                 [6, 6, 6],
                 [7, 7, 7],
                 [2, 2, 2],
                 [8, 8, 8],
                 [9, 9, 9],
                 [10, 10, 10]])

t = tf.constant([[2, 2, 2],
                 [6, 6, 6],
                 [10, 10, 10]])

# expand A in axis 1 to compare elements in A and t with broadcast
expanded_a = tf.expand_dims(A, axis=1)

# find where A and t are equal with each other
equal = tf.equal(expanded_a, t)
reduce_all = tf.reduce_all(equal, axis=2)
# find the indices
where = tf.where(reduce_all)
where = tf.cast(where, dtype=tf.int32)

# here we want to a function to find the indices to do tf.gather, if a match 
# is found in the start or
# end of A, then pick up the two elements after or before it, otherwise the 
# left one and the right one along with itself are used
@autograph.convert()
def _map_fn(x):
    if x[0] == 0:
        return tf.range(x[0], x[0] + 3)
    elif x[0] == tf.shape(A)[0] - 1:
        return tf.range(x[0] - 2, x[0] + 1)
    else:
        return tf.range(x[0] - 1, x[0] + 2)


indices = tf.map_fn(_map_fn, where, dtype=tf.int32)

# reshape the found indices to a vector
reshape = tf.reshape(indices, [-1])

# gather output with found indices
output = tf.gather(A, reshape)
```

A custom layer can be easily written as long as you understand this code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I couldn't understand all the details, what the code does exactly?  Could you add some comments to the solution you proposed, please? Also, How can I adapt it to the network inputs directly? as I mentioned in my question: `B = ...  # sum function f(in_A, in_t) to select the desired element windows as described above`. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications, I can understand better now,  but I still have 2 other questions: first the line `from tensorflow.contrib import autograph` generated an error `cannot import autograph` with python3.5 with tensorflow 1.7.0. The second question is: How can I adapt this solution for unknown inputs like : `in_A = Input(shape=(10,), dtype="int32")` and
 `in_t = Input(shape=(3,), dtype="int32")` then
 `B = ... # concatenation(selected_windows(t, A)) ?` is the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri autograph first became available in TensorFlow 1.8, but many improvements have been made since then, and I'd recommend the 1.10 release.

Comment: Thanks @alexbw, could you give a link to some examples, please?

Comment: Hi @BelkacemThiziri, we have some documentation on the TensorFlow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph

Comment: Thanks @Jie.Zhou we added a function to generate a layer using your method.